# SQL Server SP error Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, left-join

When I try to run individual query for select and/or insert, it works. When I put it in SP and run it for all DB, it errors out.

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 45 An expression of non-boolean type
> specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Addr'.

```
Declare @command varchar(MAX)
Select @command = '
         USE [?]
         IF DB_NAME() not like ''%_VER'' 
            BEGIN RETURN END
         ElSE
          BEGIN 
             Insert Into [TEST_VER].[dbo].[TestTable] 
             (ClientName,ID,Type,Filled,FilledDate,Cancelled,CancelledDate,CancellationReason,Deleted,NumberOfPosition,Address,City,State,Country,Annual,AnnualMax,FeePercentage,FeeTotal,GrossProfit,NetProfit,Rate,OTRate,CRate,COTRate,GrossProfit,GrossMargin,ProfitMargin,RegularMarkup,OTMarkup)
             select 
                 DB_NAME() as ClientName, 
                 ID, 
                 Type.Description as Type,
                 Filled,
                 FilledDate,
                 Cancelled,
                 CancelledDate,
                 CancellationReason.Description as CancellationReason,
                 Item.Deleted,
                 NumberOfPosition, 
                 Address.Description as Address,
                 City.Description as City,
                 ProvinceState.Description as State,
                 Country.Description as Country,
                 PayP.Annual,
                 PayP.AnnualMaximum,
                 PayP.FeePercentage,
                 PayP.FeeTotal,
                 PayP.GrossProfit,
                 PayP.NetProfit,
                 PayT.Rate,
                 PayT.OTRate,
                 PayT.CRate,
                 PayT.COTRate,
                 PayT.GrossProfit,
                 PayT.GrossMargin,
                 PayT.ProfitMargin,
                 PayT.RegularMarkup,
                 PayT.OTMarkup
            from [Item]
            left join [Type] on Item.TypeID = Type.TypeID AND Type.LanguageId = 1 
            left join [CancellationReason] on Item.CancellationReasonID = CancellationReason.CancellationReasonID AND CancellationReason.LanguageID = 1
            left join [Address] on Item.LocationID = Address.AddressID  
            left join [City] on Address.CityId = City.CityID
            left join [ProvinceState] on Address.ProvinceStateId = ProvinceState.ProvinceStateID
            left join [Country] on Address.CountryId = Country.CountryID
            left join [PayP] on (Item.PaymentID=PayP.ID and Item.TypeID = 1)
            left join [PayT] on (Item.PaymentID=PayT.ID and Item.TypeID > 1)
         END'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: Is that the full definition of your procedure?

Comment: Yes! I am learning to run all DB queries.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a problem with the **undocumented** `sp_msforeachdb`. I run the above and I get the error `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Pr'.` If I put the process through a user created equivilent, such as Bertrand's [`sp_foreachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) or my own [`sp_foreachdatabase`](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/) I don't get the error.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for providing links.! :) I will create my own SP for each db as `sp_msforeachdb` is limited to 2000.

Comment: I'd totally forgotten is was limited to 2,000 characters, to be honest; it's been *that* long since I've used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short response is that your sql command is too long.

This undocumented stored procedure `sp_msforeachdb` doesn't accept a varchar as long as varchar(max). In fact, on SQL SERVER 2019 as seen in the db -fiddle below it only accepts 2000 characters which results in part of your query being cut off. As a result your join expression is incomplete resulting in the error message `Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 45 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Addr'.`.

I would recommend a shorter query or creating a stored procedure with your query in a generally accessible db and then running the command from there or rewriting your query to run differently. I've also included a few suggestions at the end of this answer.

You may use the stored procedure as I have used below `sp_helptext` to find out more about the definition in your db version.

The code and reproducible sample fiddle to prove the above is shown below.

> ```sql
> select @@version;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU6) (KB4563110) - 15.0.4053.23 (X64) &lt;br&gt;        Jul 25 2020 11:26:55 &lt;br&gt;        Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation&lt;br&gt;        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 &lt;X64&gt; (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)&lt;br&gt; |
> ```

> ```sql
>  exec sp_helptext 'sp_msforeachdb'
>  GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Text                                                                                                                                                    |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

```sql
/*
 * The following table definition will be created by SQLDMO at start of each connection.
 * We don't create it here temporarily because we need it in Exec() or upgrade won't work.
 */

create proc sys.sp_MSforeachdb
    @command1 nvarchar(2000), @replacechar nchar(1) = N'?', @command2 nvarchar(2000) = null, @command3 nvarchar(2000) = null,
    @precommand nvarchar(2000) = null, @postcommand nvarchar(2000) = null
as
    set deadlock_priority low
    
    /* This proc returns one or more rows for each accessible db, with each db defaulting to its own result set */
    /* @precommand and @postcommand may be used to force a single result set via a temp table. */

    /* Preprocessor won't replace within quotes so have to use str(). */
    declare @inaccessible nvarchar(12), @invalidlogin nvarchar(12), @dbinaccessible nvarchar(12)
    select @inaccessible = ltrim(str(convert(int, 0x03e0), 11))
    select @invalidlogin = ltrim(str(convert(int, 0x40000000), 11))
    select @dbinaccessible = N'0x80000000'      /* SQLDMODbUserProf_InaccessibleDb; the negative number doesn't work in convert() */

    if (@precommand is not null)
        exec(@precommand)

    declare @origdb nvarchar(128)
    select @origdb = db_name()

    /* If it's a single user db and there's an entry for it in sysprocesses who isn't us, we can't use it. */
   /* Create the select */
    exec(N'declare hCForEachDatabase cursor global for select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases d ' +
            N' where (d.status & ' + @inaccessible + N' = 0)' +
            N' and (DATABASEPROPERTYEX(d.name, ''UserAccess'') <> ''SINGLE_USER'' and (has_dbaccess(d.name) = 1))' )

    declare @retval int
    select @retval = @@error
    if (@retval = 0)
        exec @retval = sys.sp_MSforeach_worker @command1, @replacechar, @command2, @command3, 1

    if (@retval = 0 and @postcommand is not null)
        exec(@postcommand)

   declare @tempdb nvarchar(258)
   SELECT @tempdb = REPLACE(@origdb, N']', N']]')
   exec (N'use ' + N'[' + @tempdb + N']')

    return @retval
```

Here I run the query with the `2000` max and you will see that part of the query is cut off

> ```sql
> Declare @command varchar(2000)
> Select @command = '
>          USE [?]
>          IF DB_NAME() not like ''%_VER'' 
>             BEGIN RETURN END
>          ElSE
>           BEGIN 
>              Insert Into [TEST_VER].[dbo].[TestTable] 
>              (ClientName,ID,Type,Filled,FilledDate,Cancelled,CancelledDate,CancellationReason,Deleted,NumberOfPosition,Address,City,State,Country,Annual,AnnualMax,FeePercentage,FeeTotal,GrossProfit,NetProfit,Rate,OTRate,CRate,COTRate,GrossProfit,GrossMargin,ProfitMargin,RegularMarkup,OTMarkup)
>              select 
>                  DB_NAME() as ClientName, 
>                  ID, 
>                  Type.Description as Type,
>                  Filled,
>                  FilledDate,
>                  Cancelled,
>                  CancelledDate,
>                  CancellationReason.Description as CancellationReason,
>                  Item.Deleted,
>                  NumberOfPosition, 
>                  Address.Description as Address,
>                  City.Description as City,
>                  ProvinceState.Description as State,
>                  Country.Description as Country,
>                  PayP.Annual,
>                  PayP.AnnualMaximum,
>                  PayP.FeePercentage,
>                  PayP.FeeTotal,
>                  PayP.GrossProfit,
>                  PayP.NetProfit,
>                  PayT.Rate,
>                  PayT.OTRate,
>                  PayT.CRate,
>                  PayT.COTRate,
>                  PayT.GrossProfit,
>                  PayT.GrossMargin,
>                  PayT.ProfitMargin,
>                  PayT.RegularMarkup,
>                  PayT.OTMarkup
>             from [Item]
>             left join [Type] on Item.TypeID = Type.TypeID AND Type.LanguageId = 1 
>             left join [CancellationReason] on Item.CancellationReasonID = CancellationReason.CancellationReasonID AND CancellationReason.LanguageID = 1
>             left join [Address] on Item.LocationID = Address.AddressID  
>             left join [City] on Address.CityId = City.CityID
>             left join [ProvinceState] on Address.ProvinceStateId = ProvinceState.ProvinceStateID
>             left join [Country] on Address.CountryId = Country.CountryID
>             left join [PayP] on (Item.PaymentID=PayP.ID and Item.TypeID = 1)
>             left join [PayT] on (Item.PaymentID=PayT.ID and Item.TypeID > 1)
>          END'
> select 1
> select @command
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |                1 |
> ```

```sql
USE [?]
         IF DB_NAME() not like '%_VER' 
            BEGIN RETURN END
         ElSE
          BEGIN 
             Insert Into [TEST_VER].[dbo].[TestTable] 
             (ClientName,ID,Type,Filled,FilledDate,Cancelled,CancelledDate,CancellationReason,Deleted,NumberOfPosition,Address,City,State,Country,Annual,AnnualMax,FeePercentage,FeeTotal,GrossProfit,NetProfit,Rate,OTRate,CRate,COTRate,GrossProfit,GrossMargin,ProfitMargin,RegularMarkup,OTMarkup)
             select 
                 DB_NAME() as ClientName, 
                 ID, 
                 Type.Description as Type,
                 Filled,
                 FilledDate,
                 Cancelled,
                 CancelledDate,
                 CancellationReason.Description as CancellationReason,
                 Item.Deleted,
                 NumberOfPosition, 
                 Address.Description as Address,
                 City.Description as City,
                 ProvinceState.Description as State,
                 Country.Description as Country,
                 PayP.Annual,
                 PayP.AnnualMaximum,
                 PayP.FeePercentage,
                 PayP.FeeTotal,
                 PayP.GrossProfit,
                 PayP.NetProfit,
                 PayT.Rate,
                 PayT.OTRate,
                 PayT.CRate,
                 PayT.COTRate,
                 PayT.GrossProfit,
                 PayT.GrossMargin,
                 PayT.ProfitMargin,
                 PayT.RegularMarkup,
                 PayT.OTMarkup
            from [Item]
            left join [Type] on Item.TypeID = Type.TypeID AND Type.LanguageId = 1 
            left join [CancellationReason] on Item.CancellationReasonID = CancellationReason.CancellationReasonID AND CancellationReason.LanguageID = 1
            left join [Address] on Item.LocationID = Address.AddressID  
            left join [City] on Address.CityId = City.CityID
            left join [ProvinceState] on Address.ProvinceStateId = P
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f215d6fa286b34021d6151fade47ec5)*

@Larnu has also made some suggestions about alternatives such as [option 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) and [option 2](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/) which you may consider in your own time.

Comment: Took a little to work out why that wasn't formatting properly. Tip: Stick to code fences with code (especially as you can easily specify their language). It also makes putting code blocks into block quotes really easy then. :)

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. I had originally copied directly from the fiddle but was having issues formatting the output of the queries myself. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much @ggordon. Once I re-write query and shorten it for testing, it is working.